# Trying to run a update query for access tables using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

i am just a beginner in Vba. i am able to get the select query results using recordset. But while i am trying to run the below update query code i am facing issue near execution part. i am getting  Run time error -2147217904(80040e10), No value given for one or more required parameters. Can anyone help me with this.

```
Sub Button8_Click()
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Connection

Dim Path As String

Path = "C:\Users\Documents\"

cmd.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Path & "Productivity_Tracker.accdb"



For Each chkbx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If chkbx.Value = 1 Then
        For r = 1 To Rows.Count
            If Cells(r, 1).Top = chkbx.Top Then
                'With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                    'LRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    '.Range("A" & LRow & ":D" & LRow) =

                     'Sheet3.Range("A" & r & ":F" & r).Value
                     Dim alloc_per As Integer
                     Dim emp_id As Integer
                     Dim proj_id As Integer
                     alloc_per = Sheet3.Range("E" & r).Value
                     emp_id = Sheet3.Range("A" & r).Value
                     proj_id = Sheet3.Range("B" & r).Value
                qry = "UPDATE Employee_Project_Assignment SET Employee_Project_Assignment.Allocation_Percentage = alloc_per WHERE Employee_Project_Assignment.Employee_ID = emp_id and Employee_Project_Assignment.Project_ID = proj_id"



              cmd.Execute qry

                'Exit For
            End If
        Next r
    End If
Next

Dim recordsChanged As Integer
    cmd.Execute (recordsChanged)
    If recordsChanged > 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine ("Update succesfull")
   End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Are all the fields in your SQL numeric ?

Comment: @TimWilliams yes those fields are numeric only

Answer (score 0):

You are passing literal strings "alloc_per" etc in your SQL, instead of the values held in those variables.

Try this:

```
qry = " UPDATE Employee_Project_Assignment t SET " & _
      " t.Allocation_Percentage = " & alloc_per & " WHERE " & _
      " t.Employee_ID = " & emp_id & " and " & _
      " t.Project_ID = " & proj_id
```